# $_POST['variable'] not working

Tags: php

I am having an issue getting the `$userid` from $_POST. I have done this lots of times before, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong all of a sudden.

#### Form that is submitting to user_confirm.php

```
<?php
//confirm user function
  function confirmUsers() {
    //make connection global
      global $con;

    //set user variables
    $userquery =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userlevel = 0");

    //echo list
   echo '<center><form name="userConfirm" action="functions/user_confirm.php" method="post">';
     echo '<select name="confirmUser">';
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($userquery)) {
         echo "<option value='" . $row['userid'] ."'>" . $row['username'] ."</option>"; 
         //in viewing element, the userid is displaying properly
       }
     echo '<input type="submit" value="Confirm User">';
     echo '</select>';
     echo '</form></center>';
  }
?>
```

#### user_confirm.php

```
<?php
//include db connect
  include ("db_con.php");

//set variable names
   $userid = $_POST['userid'];

//start session
  session_start();

echo $userid;


?>
```

As you can see, I am simply just trying to echo the variable passed from the form. It is not working and I am totally confused as to why, any ideas?

#### in case it was needed here is db_con.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pw","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Comment: its `confirmUser` not `userid`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont have a form field called userid, perhaps you mean the confirmUser field:

```
$userid = $_POST['confirmUser'];
```

Comment: No problem, stupid mistakes are often the easiest to overlook!

Comment: When debugging issues like this it is helpful to have a proxy viewer like 'charles' installed as well as dumping your post variable. echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); die();

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the userid var to user_confirm.php, try renaming your select to userid

Answer (score -1):

The coding looks right to me and should work. 
I'm not sure if this will help but try to load the session_start(); first.
The next thing would be to do a print_r($_POST) and see what shows.
Also view the source of the finished html and see how it prints out.
Also I like to use
echo <<

END;
With this you can just type in the html plus the strings with no ' or " unless the html needs it.

I missed the confirmUser myself.. =(